# How to generate a list of number in SQL as it was a list of comprehension?

Tags: sql, list-comprehension, sqlanywhere

In my case, using sql anywhere (sybase).

Something similar to haskell. [1..100].

I don't know how to generate a random simple list of 1 up to 100.

I only could do it doing:

```
select 1
union 
select 2
union
select 3
```

Google did not provide any sample, I suspect this feature does not exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Select 'n' records without a Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533524/sql-select-n-records-without-a-table)

Comment: @MarkByers feel free to edit the post to add tag, i cannot see what tags it should have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Anywhere contains an sa_rowgenerator stored procedure, which can be used for this purpose. For example:

```
select row_num from sa_rowgenerator( 1, 100 )
```

returns a result set of 100 rows from 1 to 100 inclusive. A link to the documentation (for version 12.0.1) is [here](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbreference/sa-rowgenerator-system-procedure.html).

**Disclaimer:** I work for SAP/Sybase in the SQL Anywhere engineering.

Comment: Finally! A solution and not a "ugly workaround". I will check other stored procedures better, i know only the basics functions from sql anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I find the easiest way for a short list is something like:

```
select t.*
from (select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as num
      from Information_Schema.columns
     ) t
where num <= 100
```

The columns table usually has at least 100 rows.  Other tables can also be used.

For large numbers, something like the following:

```
with digits as (
      select 0 as dig union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
      select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
),
     numbers as
      select d1.dig*10+d2.dig
      from digits d1 cross join
           digits d2
)
 . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Oracle queries - use any number to start/end:

 SELECT 99 + ROWNUM
   FROM dual       
 CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 100 + 1
/

SELECT 99 + LEVEL
  FROM dual       
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100 + 1
/
```

Answer (score 0):

with DD as
(
select 1 as F
union all
select 1 + F from DD where F < 100
)
select * from DD