# select statement to list numbers in range

Tags: sql, db2

In DB2, I have this query to list numbers 1-x:

```
select level from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 connect by level <= "some number"
```

But this maxes out due to `SQL20450N Recursion limit exceeded within a hierarchical query.`

How can I generate a list of numbers between 1 and x using a select statement when x is not known at runtime?

Comment: You should probably be using standard recursive SQL syntax rather than Oracle proprietary `CONNECT BY`, particularly when working with DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339369/how-to-generate-a-list-of-number-in-sql-as-it-was-a-list-of-comprehension):

```
WITH d AS
 (SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS dig FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10)
SELECT t1.n
  FROM (SELECT (d7.dig * 1000000) + 
               (d6.dig * 100000) + 
               (d5.dig * 10000) + 
               (d4.dig * 1000) + 
               (d3.dig * 100) + 
               (d2.dig * 10) + 
               d1.dig AS n
          FROM d d1
    CROSS JOIN d d2
    CROSS JOIN d d3
    CROSS JOIN d d4
    CROSS JOIN d d5
    CROSS JOIN d d6
    CROSS JOIN d d7) t1
  JOIN ("subselect that returns desired value as i") t2
    ON t1.n <= t2.i
 ORDER BY t1.n
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how I usually create lists:

For your example

```
numberlist (num) as
(
    select min(1) from anytable 
    union all
    select num + 1 from numberlist
    where num <= x
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this when I wanted a list of values to correspond with months:

```
with t1 (mon) as (                                        
  values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
)
select * from t1
```

It seems a bit kludgy, but for a small list like 1-12, or even 1-50, it did what I needed it to.

It's nice to see someone else tagging their questions with DB2.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the solution I need is for a dynamic value, not known ahead of time. I'll update the question to be more clear about that.

Comment: @Paul You know, your query works for me, even for lists of 10,000,000 numbers, though it takes a few seconds at that level.

Comment: Perhaps the recursion limit is a DB2 property that we have configured differently?

Comment: I wonder. If you're doing this kind of query a lot, have you considered creating a permanent numbers table? There seems to be a lot of advocacy out there for that approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any table known to have more than x rows, you can always do:

```
select * from (
   select row_number() over () num
      from my_big_table 
) where num <= x
```

or, per bhamby's suggestion:

```
select row_number() over () num
   from my_big_table 
   fetch first X rows only
```

Comment: For DB2, it would be much more efficient to do something like `select row_number() over () num from YOUR_BIG_TABLE fetch first X rows only`. Your method is likely going to create a work file to generate the `ROW_NUMBER`s and then filter the where. If your table is really huge, that will take a **long** time.

Comment: @bhamby, just tested on a table of 1.5 billion rows in DB2 (9.7 LUW) and that wasn't the case.  It was optimized appropriately.  However, added your suggestion as it is a bit more elegant.

Comment: I ran mine of z/OS... definitely could be a difference there.

Answer (score 0):

For DB2 you can use recursive common table expressions (cf. [IBM documentation on recursive CTE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_xmprecursivecte.html)):

```sql
with max(num) as (
  select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
,result (num) as (
  select num from max
  union ALL
  select result.num+1
  from result
  where result.num<=100
)
select * from result;
```