# How to split a semicolon separated value to rows for multiple columns in a table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with multiple columns having non definite multiple values in different columns.

How do I make those multiple rows ?

E.g;

```
ABC                         DEF                     GHI
4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;;;;;;;; 1;1;1;1;1;1;1;;1;;;1;1  ;;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;8
```

I tried with this method, it works but as it does cross join so takes a huge lot of time to execute.

```
select 
    t1.*
from   
    (select
         LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Rule_T
    from 
        ('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(t2.ABC,';','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x, ) t
CROSS APPLY 
    x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```

Comment: What is the result expected to look like for the different columns? Have you tried [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)?

Comment: The expected result would be like :
ABC DEF     GHI
4      1          NULL
4      1          NULL
4      1          8
4       NULL  8
4       NULL  8

Means the column which has values after getting aligned will have values and those which doesnt have will be null.

Comment: Please edit your question. It's not possible to understand that from the comments.

Comment: How about DelimitedSplit8k?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `SUBSTRING()` cross joined with union query of every other character index (1, 3, 5, ...) if the number of split columns is feasible. But first thing to do is to pad empty sections `;;` with spaces `; ;` (of course contingency made if string begins with `;`).

```
CREATE TABLE #semiColonData (ABC VARCHAR(255), DEF VARCHAR(255), GHI VARCHAR(255));
INSERT #semiColonData (ABC, DEF, GHI)
VALUES ('4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;;;;;;;;', 
        '1;1;1;1;1;1;1;;1;;;1;1', 
        ';;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;8;8');

SELECT 
     CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(t.nABC,s.ID,1) = ' ' THEN NULL 
          ELSE SUBSTRING(t.nABC,s.ID,1) END AS ABC, 

     CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(t.nDEF,s.ID,1) = ' ' THEN NULL         
          ELSE SUBSTRING(t.nDEF,s.ID,1) END AS DEF, 

     CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(t.nGHI,s.ID,1) = ' ' THEN NULL 
          ELSE SUBSTRING(t.nGHI,s.ID,1) END AS GHI

FROM 
(SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(
                CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(ABC, 1, 1)=';' THEN ' '+ABC ELSE ABC END, 
                ';;', '; ;'), 
        ';;', '; ;') AS nABC,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(
                CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DEF, 1, 1)=';' THEN ' '+DEF ELSE DEF END, 
                 ';;', '; ;'), 
        ';;', '; ;') AS nDEF,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(GHI, 1, 1)=';' THEN ' '+GHI ELSE GHI END, 
                 ';;', '; ;'), 
        ';;', '; ;') AS nGHI
 FROM #semiColonData) t, 

(SELECT 1 AS ID UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL SELECT 7
                UNION ALL SELECT 9  UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 13
                UNION ALL SELECT 15 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 19
                UNION ALL SELECT 21 UNION ALL SELECT 23 UNION ALL SELECT 25 
                UNION ALL SELECT 27 UNION ALL SELECT 29
                UNION ALL SELECT 31 UNION ALL SELECT 33) As s;
```

Alternatively, for a dynamic need to avoid all the UNIONs and if delimiters run very high to be not feasible with above, consider a [recursive CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533524/sql-select-n-records-without-a-table) as shown here by @Dave Markle:

```
DECLARE @start INT = 1;
DECLARE @end INT = 35;

WITH numbers AS (
    SELECT @start AS ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID + 2 
    FROM  numbers
    WHERE ID < @end
)

SELECT      
     CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(t.nABC,s.ID,1) = ' ' THEN NULL 
          ELSE SUBSTRING(t.nABC,s.ID,1) END AS ABC, 

     CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(t.nDEF,s.ID,1) = ' ' THEN NULL         
          ELSE SUBSTRING(t.nDEF,s.ID,1) END AS DEF, 

     CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(t.nGHI,s.ID,1) = ' ' THEN NULL 
          ELSE SUBSTRING(t.nGHI,s.ID,1) END AS GHI  
FROM 

(SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(
                CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(ABC, 1, 1)=';' THEN ' '+ABC ELSE ABC END, 
                ';;', '; ;'), 
        ';;', '; ;') AS nABC,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(
                CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DEF, 1, 1)=';' THEN ' '+DEF ELSE DEF END, 
                 ';;', '; ;'), 
        ';;', '; ;') AS nDEF,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(GHI, 1, 1)=';' THEN ' '+GHI ELSE GHI END, 
                 ';;', '; ;'), 
        ';;', '; ;') AS nGHI
 FROM #semiColonData) t, 

(SELECT ID FROM numbers) s;
```

**Output**

```
-- ABC      DEF     GHI
-- 4        1       NULL
-- 4        1       NULL
-- 4        1       8
-- 4        1       8
-- 4        1       8
-- 4        1       8
-- 4        1       8
-- 4        NULL    8
-- 4        1       8
-- 4        NULL    8
-- NULL     NULL    8
-- NULL     1       8
-- NULL     1       8
-- NULL     NULL    8
-- NULL     NULL    8
-- NULL     NULL    NULL
-- NULL     NULL    NULL
-- NULL     NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Hi Parfait,

The above CTE code doesn't work sadly :(, and throws error after the comma specified after "AS ABC,"

Comment: See edit the `CASE` statements needed an `END`. Also, just occurred to me above assumes 1 character in between semicolons (as posted example) which might not align to actual data.